# JQuery plug-in doesn't work after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

AJAX calls seem to disable my jQuery plugin. I've tried it on three plug-ins, so assume it's a fault with my code, not the plugin.

To simplify, I have:

```
<div id="Static">Not affected by AJAX</div>
<div id="Dynamic">Hello</div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
<button id="print">Print</button>
```

On pressing print, I use the printArea plug-in:

```
<script src="../jquery.PrintArea.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#print", function(e) {
e.preventDefault;
$('#Static').printArea();
})
```

I have it printing the Static content, to rule out the problem being about the plug-in not working on changed content. When I press "Change", the Dynamic content changes:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#change", function(){
    var data = "1";
$.ajax({url:"X.php", type:"POST", data:{'mydata': data}, success:function(result){
$("#Dynamic").html(result);
}});
})

</script>
```

I'm not copying the X.php code in, as that works fine, and I don't think that's the problem. Assume it changes "Hello" to "Goodbye".

So essentially, if I press "Print" first, it will print out "Not affected by AJAX". If I press "Change", Hello is replaced by Goodbye. If I press "Print" after "Change", nothing happens.

How do I ensure my jQuery plug-in works after the AJAX call?

Thanks!

Comment: Html is case insensitive, so Dynamic is equal to dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
$.getScript("jquery.PrintArea.js")
```

into the success function works... With bugs, but I think that's due to the more complicated part of my code I've omitted here.